# How can I make objects appear at intervals that decrease over time in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'll like to make some elements in an array appear at different times, the time will be decreasing over time (so the elements will appear faster and faster). I had tried with setTimeout and setInterval with no luck, I think it is because I'm looping through the array.

Comment: could you please include a minimum viable code example to better explain what you are trying to achieve along with that you have already tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple p5.js example that should hopefully point you in the right direction.

I'm calling the `setTimeout` function for every object on initialisation. The delay of the timeout is incremented by a value `incrementor` which decreases each iteration.

```js
let circles = [];
let count = 100;
let incrementor = 500;
let delay = 500;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let circle = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height),
      show: false,
      
    }
    incrementor *= 0.9;
    delay += incrementor;
    setTimeout(() => circle.show = true, delay);
    circles.push(circle);
    
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noStroke()
  fill(0, 128, 128);
  for (let circle of circles) {
    if (circle.show) {
      ellipse(circle.x, circle.y, 10, 10);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that via intervals. Yet, it's possible with recursive timeouts. For example, let's say that the time is decreasing by 2x:

```js
const initialDuration = 10000;

function someAnimation(duration) {
    // Your animation code here...

    setTimeout(() => someAnimation(duration / 2), duration);
}

someAnimation(initialDuration);
```